# Transpose CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

**My Goal:**

I have a csv file and I want to change the contents of the row and its column together (*Transpose* it)

**What I done:**

I used `izip` as follow:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

a = izip(*csv.reader(open("my_file.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
```

**My Error:**

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TransposeCSV.py", line 2, in <module>
    from itertools import izip
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip'
```

**My Question:**

What is the problem or is there another way to transpose my csv file?

Comment: If you are using Python 3 than built-in `zip` is the same as the `izip`, so I would suggest you to use `zip` instead.

Comment: I use `zip` instead of `izip`, but i get this error: `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

Comment: This error solved with `open("my_file.csv", "rt")` instead of `open("my_file.csv", "rb")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`izip` is only available in Python 2 under the `itertools` package. In Python 3, the same functionality is available through the `zip` built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you found a Python 2 Tutorial on this and are trying it with Python 3? In Python 3 you can use `zip` almost the same as izip from itertools in Python 2, even has better performance.